# IIS and Coldfusion concurrent requests limit

Tags: iis, coldfusion, windows-server

I am using IIS and JRun to serve coldfusion application.

Something is limiting maximum number of concurrent connections - they never get above 25.

My application is waiting for response from external services for long time and could possibly handle much more concurrent requests.

I've found only one value that may have something to do with this:
In `jrun.xml` `activeHandlerThreads` is set to `100`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution finnally found: [IIS 6/IIS 7 for ColdFusion 9: Increasing the Number of Worker Threads](http://blogs.adobe.com/cfdoc/2009/12/iis_6_for_coldfusion_9_increasing_the_number_of_worker_threads.html)

There is a magical `C:\JRun4\lib\wsconfig\1\jrun_iis6_wildcard.ini` file with:

```
#maxworkerthreads=25 <number of worker threads created for asynchronous request processing>
```

The default is 25, to increase concurrent requests uncomment this line and change the value.
For example:

```
maxworkerthreads=50 <number of worker threads created for asynchronous request processing>
```

Then you need to restart both IIS (whole server, not single website) and JRun service.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the limits under Requset tuning in the Server settings section within the ColdFusion administrator. Should be self explanatory from there.

Comment: Thanks for answer.
"Maximum number of simultaneous * request" is set to 100
"Maximum number of running JRun threads" is set to 500
I've tried increasing it even more and it doesn't help.

Comment: Seems excessive, did you did restart the ColdFusion process?

Comment: Yes, both JRun and ISS but it doesn't change anything.